# Install .xla Excel add-on for all users?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-registry, addons

When you add a new `.XLA` add-on using Excel it only adds it for the current user.
Is there a possibility to add it for all the users of the computer even with editing registry?

Answer (score 4):

Excel normally loads addins based on per user example below:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Options]
>   "OPEN"="c:\someapp\exceladdin.xla"
>   "OPEN1"="c:\someapp1\exceladdin.xla"

For each excel addin there is an OPENn (where n is a number) e.g. OPEN, OPEN1, OPEN2 etc.

Note that it depends on the current version of Excel:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Options

You can build a vb script that would do the trick. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Check how many `OPEN` keys you have for each user in the REG (users may already have an xla loading at startup)
2. Add an OPEN value (REG_SZ) with the path to the xla file

Note that some Excel addins use the following registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins
```

Comment: does that imply that if you don't have an OPEN but do have, say, an OPEN4, that the OPEN4 won't get evaluated?

Comment: The question was about whether it's possible to install an addin for all users. Would the advice here work if we replaced `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`? Also, can you please answer the **boost**'s question?

Comment: @bugmagnet On Excel 2007 (!), I made an `OPEN99` in `HKCU\...\12.0\...\Options`.  When I started Excel, it did not load that add-in.  However, it *did* rename my `OPEN99` to `OPEN3` (which happened to be the next available on my system).  I exited and restarted Excel, and my add-in loaded fine!  `OPEN128` also worked :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can import ntuser.dat file from `c:\users\default` and name it something. Then modify that key `HKEY_USERS\SOMETHING\software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options` and make the add-in(s) start for any new user of the machine.

This trick works well for a lab admin who is refreshing the desktop after each student logs off.